# Making desktop apps in Elixir

Tags: elixir, wxwidgets, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

### Background

In my quest to make a desktop app with Elixir for Windows (I have given up the idea of doing multi-desktop apps for now) I am trying to create a HelloWorld Desktop app.

This app is basically what you get from running mix phx.new hello.
I am using Phoenix’s latest version, so I don’t have to deal with SASS nor anything alike, which honestly is a blessing since this means I don’t have any more node-gyp issues.
Making it desktop friendly

As some of you may have realized however, just creating a Phoenix project won’t make it a Desktop app.
This is where the Desktop project comes in:

- https://github.com/elixir-desktop/desktop

This is a dependency that allows you to make your applications Desktop like.
Since I have run the Sample app in the past:

- https://github.com/elixir-desktop/desktop-example-app

I figured I would try to tear it apart and try to launch the simplest, dummiest HelloWorld app I could.
Basically, when I run `mix iex -S` I want it to instead of opening a window in my browser for it to open a desktop app.

### Problem

I have added all the dependencies and I have a somewhat similar project structure to what the sample app has:

***mix.exs***

```
defmodule Hello.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :hello,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.12",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers(),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [
      mod: {Hello.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :runtime_tools, :inets, :observer, :wx]
    ]
  end

  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]

  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.6.2"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 3.0"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.16.0"},
      {:floki, ">= 0.30.0", only: :test},
      {:phoenix_live_dashboard, "~> 0.5"},
      {:esbuild, "~> 0.2", runtime: Mix.env() == :dev},
      {:swoosh, "~> 1.3"},
      {:telemetry_metrics, "~> 0.6"},
      {:telemetry_poller, "~> 1.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.18"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.2"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.5"},

      {:desktop, github: "elixir-desktop/desktop", tag: "v1.3.1"},
      {:credo, "~> 1.5", only: [:dev, :test], runtime: false}
    ]
  end

  defp aliases do
    [
      setup: ["deps.get"],
      "assets.deploy": ["esbuild default --minify", "phx.digest"]
    ]
  end
end
```

However, nothing I do works. There are no errors in the console, but the desktop app won’t start.
I am willing to throw everything away, all I want is to have a way of opening this in a desktop window.

I think there might be a config issue, but I can’t be sure since the sample app is done with an older version of Phoenix that uses SASS.

### Question

Can someone help me figure out what is the MNE to have this open a desktop window?

I have the project open sourced here:

- https://github.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/hello-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled down you code and it seems to work just fine. You need to run it with `iex -S mix phx.server` or `mix phx.server` thought instead.

A couple of things:

1. `iex` is not a mix task it's the interactive elixir shell you can run your program with an interactive shell by calling `iex` with `-S` the script tag followed by you mix command.
2. You app is as most phoenix app are, to boot the endpoint when you call `mix phx.server` otherwise the app will start without spinning up the endpoint that allows it to respond to web requests. Elixir-Desktop launches with the endpoint.